# MySQL: UPDATE column WHERE column STARTS WITH " " (Blankspace)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, trim, string-function

I need to search and UPDATE my database for column values starting with a blankspace..

**SQL**

```
UPDATE table
  SET column substring(column, 1)
  WHERE column has blankspace
```

How can i do this?

**EDIT**
Oh yeah.
Reason is to erase blankspace...

Comment: Never more than 1 blankspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**LTRIM()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim) function to remove starting blank spaces.

Try this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = LTRIM(column)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be explicit and use `like`:

```
UPDATE table
  SET column = substring(column, 1)
  WHERE column like ' %';
```